# How can I convert existing Leads into Contact, Account, Opportunity Objects

Tags: apex, opportunity, account, contact, lead-conversion

```
public class LeadConvert {
    public void convertToAccount(){
        account acc=new account();
        contact con=new contact();
        opportunity opp=new opportunity();
        list<contact>conlist=new list<contact>();
        list<opportunity>opplist=new list<opportunity>();
        list<account>acclist=new list<account>();
        list <Lead> ldList = [Select Name,Company,OwnerId,id From Lead];
        try{
            for(Lead ld : ldList){
                acc.name=ld.company;
                acc.Id=ld.Id;
                acc.OwnerId=ld.OwnerId;
                con.lastname=acc.name;    
                con.accountid=acc.id;
                opp.name=acc.name;
                opp.stagename='Prospecting';
                opp.closedate=system.today();
                opp.accountid=acc.id; 
            } 
            acclist.add(acc);
            conlist.add(con);
            opplist.add(opp);
            insert conlist;
            insert opplist;
            insert acclist;
        }  
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            system.debug(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lead can converted using `Database.LeadConvert`. On conservion lead it will create the account, contact and opportunity(optional).

```
  public class LeadConvert {
  public void convertToAccount() {
    LeadStatus convertStatus = [select MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted = true limit 1];
    List <Database.LeadConvert> leadConverts = new List < Database.LeadConvert > ();

    for (Lead lead: [Select Name, Company, OwnerId, id From Lead]) {
      if (!lead.isConverted) {
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
            
        lc.setLeadId(lead.Id);
        lc.setOpportunityName(lead.Name);
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

        leadConverts.add(lc);
      }
    }

    if (!leadConverts.isEmpty()) {
      List < Database.LeadConvertResult > lcr = Database.convertLead(leadConverts);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Amol. I saved this class in my org and run it using the Anonymous window..The result was null, nothing was converted. Can you tell me pls, what can I do to convert existing Leads into Account, Opportunities, and Contacts?

Comment: @Azizbek the same code is working. make sure you have valid record, and put debug log to check is record fetch by soql.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use LeadConvert Class, The convertLead Database method converts a lead into an account and contact or an account and person account, as well as (optionally) an opportunity.

Check out the link for help:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_dml_convertLead.htm